# DOI link with special characters

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls, doi

I use the bibtexstyle [statto](http://www.jorrit.org/typo3/uploads/media/statto.bst) which gives a hyperlink of the DOI to the respective site. For the title it seems to take preferentially the url provided in the bibtex file. I have few DOIs of the form `10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A` In this case the hyperlink is not valid. The hyperlink in the PDF shows well `http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-‌​‌​A` but when I click on it I get an error (The Web Capture operation you have requested has failed because of an error).
Copying the link from the journal webpage gives a link where the special characters are replaced `http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract` which works fine (hyperlinked in the titel). How can I modify the DOI to produce a correct hyperlink?

Eventually there is a possibility to modify the statto file to exchange the special characters in the link? I think the `doi` package does something like this. However, loading the `doi` package does not help. Loading the `doi` package and using `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` gives a working link. However I would like to have the titles hyperlinked,  as statto.bst provides.

Comment: The link in the PDF seems to work fine when viewed with AcrobatReader 10, but not in Adobe Acrobat Pro 10 (give the error stated above). So the link might work in most cases, however a solution avoiding the special characters would still be appreciated.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib2.bib}

@ARTICLE{Lopez-Carreno_SurfaceandInterfaceAnalysis_1998,
  author = {L\'opez-Carre\~no, L. D. and Ben\'itez, G. and Viscido, L. and Heras,
    J. M. and Yubero, F. and Espin\'os, J. P. and Gonz\'alez-Elipe, A.
    R.},
  title = {Oxidation of molybdenum surfaces by reactive oxygen plasma and {O}$_2^+$
    bombardment: an auger and {XPS} study},
  journal = {Surface and Interface Analysis},
  year = {1998},
  volume = {26},
  pages = {235--241},
  number = {4},
  doi = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A},
  issn = {1096-9918},
  keywords = {ballistic effects, molybdenum oxides, oxygen plasma, {XPS}},
  language = {en},
  shorttitle = {Oxidation of molybdenum surfaces by reactive oxygen plasma and O2+
    bombardment},
  url = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract},
}



\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[square, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}



\begin{document}

A citation \cite{Lopez-Carreno_SurfaceandInterfaceAnalysis_1998}

\bibliographystyle{statto}
\bibliography{mytestbib2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: If you go to the [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract) you provided you get the option to export a citation for this article in various formats. One of the options is the BibTeX format.

When I exported the citation the DOI was exported to the .bib file as `doi = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A}` and the URL as `url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A}`

Don't the above reprsentations of the citation work for you?

Comment: I complemented it with a minimal example. The doi and url field are exactly like this, but it does not provide a working hyperlink for the doi.

Comment: Try escaping the `%` with `\ ` (that is, replace it for `\%`) on your url and see what happens

Comment: the url created from `url={}` works fine, but not the url created from the doi. I go with the mouse over it it shows well `http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-‌​A` but when I click on it in the PDF I get an error (The Web Capture operation you have requested has failed because of an error)

Comment: @tohecz The lik to the file is provided in the question (statto is hyperlinked)

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be that the DOI is not a DOI at all. None of --- `dx.doi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A` --- `dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A` --- `dx.doi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract` --- `dx.doi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract` --- works for me in the browser (independently of any PDF or whatever).

Comment: I think wiley has right now some problems. At least `dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9918(199804)26:4<235::AID-SIA360>3.0.CO;2-A` and `dx.doi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-9918%28199804%2926:4%3C235::AID-SIA360%3E3.0.CO;2-A` (at least when copying the doi part from my question and not from your comment (or mine)) is forwarded to wiley.

Comment: @tohecz The site of Wiley seems to be working again, and the two links work fine when putting them in the browser

Comment: Yes, it works. However, if I compile your file, I don't see any problem. Both links in the PDF file work correctly. So I don't see what the question is about...

Comment: @tohecz For me only the first link works and not the second. With the second I get the error: `The Web Capture operation you have requested has failed because of an error`
Could this depend on the PDF viewer or the compilation if it works for you?

Comment: Probably depends on the browser. It works for me in TeXworks 0.2.3 and AcroRead 9. I compile with `pdflatex` from TeXlive2012.

Comment: With AcrobatReader 10 it doesn't, and as the error occurs within the pdf, I can't imagine that it depends on the browser

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11403/discussion-between-tohecz-and-user2758804)

Comment: You can use http://shortdoi.org/ to create a short alias DOI.